# ArrayList Index out of bounds exception on only object in the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I know this has probably been asked many times before, but I have a problem and I could not find a solution that particularly targeted my issue.

The problem is as follows:

I have two arraylists of rockets and projectiles, and collision is checked between them. When they collide, both of them are removed. The problem is that when the only rocket in the arraylist is hit, the exception occurs, and I have no idea how to stop it from happening.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at adam.miszczak.defendthebase.level.Level.collision(Level.java:158)
at adam.miszczak.defendthebase.level.Level.tick(Level.java:144)
at adam.miszczak.defendthebase.Game.tick(Game.java:124)
at adam.miszczak.defendthebase.Game.run(Game.java:104)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Collision method + the arraylists:

```
public static ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();
private static ArrayList<Rocket> rockets = new ArrayList<Rocket>();

private void collision(){
    for(int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < projectiles.size(); j++){
            try{
                if(rockets.get(i).bounds().intersects(projectiles.get(j).bounds())){
                    projectiles.remove(j);
                    rockets.get(i).die();
                    stats.addScore(rockets.get(i));
                    Particle p = new Particle(20, 20, 20, 50);
                    particles.add(p);
                }
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove and Add methods:

```
private void remove(ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles, ArrayList<Rocket> rockets){
    for(int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++){
        if(rockets.get(i).getVisible()){ rockets.remove(i); rocketsOnScreen--; }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++){
        if(projectiles.get(i).isRemoved()){ projectiles.remove(i);}
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++){
        if(planes.get(i).isRemoved()){ planes.remove(i); planesOnLevel--;}
    }
}

private void spawnRocket(int rocketType, int x, ArrayList<Rocket> rockets) {
    switch (rocketType) {
        case ROCKET_NORMAL:
            rockets.add(new NormalRocket(x, -10, 80, 0, 2));
            rocketsSpawned++;
            rocketsOnScreen++;
            break;
        case ROCKET_FIRE:
            if(difficulty > 1 && random.nextInt(100) > fireRocketSpawn){
                    rockets.add(new FireRocket(x, -10, 70, 0, 2));
                    rocketsSpawned++;
                    rocketsOnScreen++;
            }else{
                return;
            }
            break;
        case ROCKET_ZIPPER:
            if(difficulty > 2 && random.nextInt(100) > zipperRocketSpawn){
                rockets.add(new ZipperRocket(x, -10, 40, 0, 4));
                rocketsSpawned++;
                rocketsOnScreen++;
            }else{
                return;
            }
            break;
        case ROCKET_TANK:
            if(difficulty > 3 && random.nextInt(100) > tankRocketSpawn){
                rockets.add(new TankRocket(x, -10, 130, 0, 1));
                rocketsSpawned++;
                rocketsOnScreen++;
            }else{
                return;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

NOTE: rocket.die() basically just removes the rocket, the same way the remove method would do.

Comment: @ppeterka66 The rangeCheck() method is within the ArrayList class. I don't have it within my code.

Comment: You can't remove from a list while iterating over it with a `for` loop. Use an iterator instead.

Comment: You seem to be looping over `projectiles` and removing from it. A **big** no-no.

Comment: @Adam aaahhhh... _Maybe_ it is time for me to get to sleep now...

Comment: @svz That should set me on the right path, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** remove while iterating over a `List` with anything other than an `Iterator`. Imagine the consequences; you are looping over the elements and remove element `n`. All other elements shift down one to fill the gap. You take element `n+1`, this is now element `n+2` from when you started looping. And the `List` is one element smaller so your bounds check is now wrong. You can get all sorts of hard to track-down bugs in this manner.

In Java if you use the **proper** syntax - i.e. [enhanced foreach loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) then your will get the correct error if you even try to addto/deletefrom the list while iterating - you will get a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

To fix your method, 1) get rid of all the indices. You are abusing them and they are unnecessary (now many times do you get the *same* element from each `List` in each iteration?) . 2) use an actual [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) for the inner loop so that you can call `Iterator.remove` to remove the last returned element from the `List`. Because that is done via the `Iterator` it doesn't result in an error:

```
private void collision() {
    for (final Rocket rocket : rockets) {
        final Iterator<Projectile> iter = projectiles.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            final Projectile projectile = iter.next();
            if (rocket.bounds().intersects(projectile.bounds())) {
                rocket.die();
                stats.addScore(rocket);
                Particle p = new Particle(20, 20, 20, 50);
                particles.add(p);
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation and answer/fix, but this throws a ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @AdamMiszczak well then you are editing the `List`s from elsewhere in your code. Which you should not be doing. Find where and fix. Easy. Ish.

Comment: Ok, but I need to have add and remove methods for the rockets, since the game wouldn't work otherwise. Would synchronizing the methods work or should I somehow put everything into one method, or call everything before collision? Sorry if this is a dumb question; this is my first time doing such "heavy" tasks with arraylists.

Comment: Question mark over _heavy_. You can add and remove all you want, but you absolutely **must** use the `Iterator`. If you want to add you can use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) - it has an `add`, you can get one by calling [`List.listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()). The alternative approach is to create one (or more) temporary `List`s of elements to remove/add and then use `removeAll` and `addAll` to apply changes after. `synchronized` has **absolutely nothing** to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Never remove items of a list during a loop through the list. It might give concurrency oroblems. Mark the numbers for removal right after the loop.

Not sure if it will fix your problem, but sure enough you should fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

When the collision is detected you call

```
rockets.get(i).die();
```

'die' removes the rocket from the 'Arraylist', you say. Then you call

```
stats.addScore(rockets.get(i));
```

which will crash (this line is 158, isn't it? )

Apologies for brevity and formatting, first answer from my phone :-)

Comment: Again, this doesn't fix the issue. You cannot loop and remove from the same `List`. Ask yourself what happens to the indices.

Comment: No it doesn't. It pinpoints immediate cause, addressing the OP. Agree completely with your comments about modifying during iteration. OP should be marking objects as "dead" during the loop, and remove them later.

Comment: No need for that, just the use of an `Iterator` you do. No need to create temporary lists and all that jazz.